Как конвертировать IEnumerable в массив?
Выполняю учебную задачу по поиску кратчайшего маршрута для обхода списка чекпоинтов роботом-пылесосом)) Нужно написать класс, основной метод которого при помощи пары вспомогательных переберет все возможные варианты маршрутов, оценит расстояния и вернет лучший найденный маршрут. Как я не ломал голову, а всё же мне кажется, что здесь лучшим решением будет применение "ленивой" генерации маршрутов (yield return). Проблема в том, что в этом случае возвращаемое значение у такого метода должно быть одним из этих четырех:
IEnumerable,
IEnumerable<T>,
IEnumerator,
IEnumerator<T>.

С интерфейсами я ещё не знаком, это будет объясняться в курсе далее. Может скажу глупость, но мне нужно вместо IEnumerable<T> получить обычный массив. Вроде бы это можно сделать так же, как и с любой другой коллекцией - метод ToArray(), и дело в шляпе. Только вот для IEnumerable используется какая-то незнакомая мне перегрузка этого метода, и я никак не могу понять, как же все таки этот несчастный массив получить. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Было бы здорово посмотреть правильную запись - вроде бы это должна быть всего одна строка. Заранее спасибо!

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

У вас ошибка в том что после преобразования коллекции в массив, которая внутри содержит массив, получается двойной(зубчатый) массив. Соответственно чтобы принять его вам нужно переменную int[][] bestOrder = ...
А по поводу yield return представьте что он возращает одно значение в последовательности, каждый раз когда это понадобиться при перечеслении этой последовательности например в Foreach, чтобы взять один элемент он будет обращаться к вашему методу брать элемент в Yield return и возращаться обратно в логику foreach, либо в том же методе .ToArray() будет происходить тоже самое, потому что .ToArray внутри себя переберает вашу последовательность, примерно так же как и foreach, но только с сохранением кажого элемента в результирующий массив.

Спасибо за ответ! Это не ошибка, а непонимание - с IEnumerable еще не знаком. Мне нужно не менять принимающую переменную, а возвращать из метода именно то, что нужно для конкретной задачи - вопрос именно в этом и заключается.

Если вы хотите это сделать лениво , вы можете попробовать сделать так.
FindBestCheckpointsOrder(Point[] checkpoints) { foreach(int[] bestOrder from MakeTrivialPermutation(checkpoints.Length)) {  //bestOrder это будет ваш ленивый массив        if(  Check(bestOrder)  )  //Ваша еще одна проверка ну и как вы хотели "пауза" для чего хотите                 return bestOrder; } }

Можно короткое уточнение - как это должно работать? Я только учусь, воображение ещё плохо развито...

Ваш метод возвращает IEnumerable<int[]> , перечисление массивов. Foreach под капотом работает с перечислениями, чтобы получить ему первый элемент(просто массив) он обращается к вашему перечисл.(интерфейс IEnumerable) который реализует метод GetEnumerator(), у него соответственно есть метод MoveNext() и свойство Current, и чтобы Foreach перечислить I элемент вашего перечисления ему нужно вызывать метод MoveNext() внутри которого будет делегат вашего метода с итератором yield return который и вернет ваш первый элемент в foreach. И каждый раз при прохождении цикла foreach будет вызывать MoveNext

То есть, если я правильно понял, вы предлагаете использовать foreach для того, чтобы обратиться к единственному элементу внутри IEnumerable<int[]>, потому что foreach уже содержит в себе все необходимые методы и свойства. Грубо говоря, с помощью foreach мы попадем как бы "внутрь" IEnumerable, а оттуда сможем уже работать с содержащимся внутри массивом. Верно понял? Если да, то вполне неплохой вариант, опробую. Спасибо)

Да , верно. А yield return будет вам возвращать по одному элементу каждый цикл foreach

Спасибо за помощь, уже опробовал - всё работает!

Чтобы получить один элемент из коллекции IEnumerable<int[]>, которую возвращает метод MakeTrivialPermutation, необходимо к нему обратиться конкретно. Либо, допустим, через ElementAt(int index), либо через Last(), First() и т.д. После чего этот элемент уже не нужно будет преобразовывать в одномерный массив посредством ToArray().
int[] bestOrder = MakeTrivialPermutation(checkpoints.Length).ElementAt(0);
int[] bestOrder = MakeTrivialPermutation(checkpoints.Length).Last();


Спасбо за ответ! Задача другая. Мне не нужен один элемент, мне нужен массив. Суть в том, что метод за один полный цикл своей работы генерирует несколько десятков таких массивов, вот я и хотел этот процесс "притормозить", чтобы не париться о том, где хранить эти массивы, и как в них не запутаться. Вернул один массив - встал на паузу. Другой метод проверил возвращенный массив, он не подошел - вызвал новую генерацию. И естественно, результаты должны быть каждый раз разные и не повторяться. Поэтому я хотел ленивую генерацию, и поэтому нужно возвращать именно массив, а не отдельный элемент.

Я понял задачу по комментариям. Ну так отдельный элемент для IEnumerable<int[]> - это и есть массив. Еще раз, чтобы не генерировать методом MakeTrivialPermutation целиком всю последовательность, необходимо обращаться к конкретному ее элементу. А уже сам элемент является требуемым массивом.

Хмммммм.... А ведь и правда...)) Спасибо большое, пойду тестить)))

Вам нужно решить задачу или пообсуждать IEnumerable?
Поскольку набор маршрутов представляет из себя дерево, то для решения нужно использовать рекурсию.
Я бы собрал координаты чекпоинтов в двухсвязный список.
Беру (вырываю) из списка чекпоинты по очереди и спрашиваю у каждого кратчайший маршрут (список чекпоинтов и длину) по оставшимся в списке. Прибавляю к длине маршрута расстояние до этого чекпоинта и нахожу минимальный маршрут.
P. S. Вот вариант решения. Из оптимизации здесь матрица расстояний между точками и отсечение длинных веток. Причём, если сделать матрицу треугольной, то время выполнения увеличивается. Входные данные - строки с координатами точек, разделёнными табуляцией. В первой строке - начальная точка. Конечная точка - произвольная. Если нужна определённая конечная точка, то алгоритм нужно немного изменить.
namespace VCRobot;

internal class Program {

    class Point {
        public int X, Y, Id; public int Next, Previous;
        public Point() { }
        public Point(int x, int y, int id) {
            X = x; Y = y; Id = id; Next = id + 1; Previous = id - 1;
        }
        public double DistanceM(Point p) {
            return r[Id, p.Id] ??=
                Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.X - X, 2) + Math.Pow(p.Y - Y, 2));
        }
    }

    static int N;
    static Point[] points;
    static int[] route, shroute;
    static double?[,] r;
    static double shdist;

    static void Remove(int i) {
        var p = points[i];
        points[p.Previous].Next = p.Next; points[p.Next].Previous = p.Previous;
    }

    static void Restore(int i) {
        var p = points[i]; points[p.Previous].Next = points[p.Next].Previous = i;
    }

    static double? GetRoute(int rootnode, int M, double baseroute) {
        Remove(rootnode); var curnode = points[0].Next; double? mindist = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            route[N - M - 1] = rootnode;
            var dist = points[rootnode].DistanceM(points[curnode]);
            var basedist = baseroute + dist;
            if (basedist < shdist) {
                var tailor = M == 1 ? 0 : GetRoute(curnode, M - 1, basedist);
                if (tailor != null) {
                    var curdist = baseroute + dist + (double)tailor;
                    mindist = shdist - baseroute;
                    if (M == 1 && curdist < shdist) {
                        shdist = curdist; route[N - 1] = curnode;
                        Array.ConstrainedCopy(route, 0, shroute, 0, N);
                    }
                }
            }
            curnode = points[curnode].Next;
        }
        Restore(rootnode); return mindist;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
        var pts = new List<Point>([new Point() { Next = N = 1 }]);
        pts.AddRange(lines.Select(s => { var sa = s.Split('\t');
            return new Point(Convert.ToInt32(sa[0]), Convert.ToInt32(sa[1]), N++);
        }));
        pts.Add(new Point() { Previous = N - 1 }); points = pts.ToArray();
        r = new double?[N, N]; route = new int[--N]; shroute = new int[N];
        shdist = double.MaxValue; var t = DateTime.Now; GetRoute(1, N - 1, 0);
    var s = DateTime.Now - t;
    Console.WriteLine($"Shortest route is {shdist}: {string.Join(' ', shroute)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Execution time is {s.TotalMilliseconds:F0} ms");
    }
}

Тест 1 - "data.txt" и результат:
1   2
3   4
1   4
3   2
1   3
4   2
-3  -4
-1  -4
-3  -2
-1  -3
-4  -2
1   1
-1  -1

-->

Shortest route is 20,30056307974577: 1 5 3 2 6 4 12 13 10 8 7 9 11
Execution time is 27 ms

Тест 2 - "data.txt" и результат:
1   1
8   8
5   5
3   3
9   9
6   6
11  11
2   2
13  13
10  10
12  12
4   4
7   7

-->

Shortest route is 16,970562748477146: 1 8 4 12 3 6 13 2 5 10 7 11 9
Execution time is 15 ms

P. P. S. Задача не для новичка, конечно.

Для лирических рассуждений и уточняющих вопросов есть комментарии. Ответы - для ответов.

Это и есть задача в разделе про рекурсию. Допустим, у нас есть 5 чекпоинтов. Рекурсивный метод за один полный цикл рекурсивных вызовов генерирует некоторую последовательность чисел без повторений (перестановки). Эту последовательность (массив из 5 чисел) метод возвращает через yield return, затем при следующем вызове возвращается назад и генерирует следующую последовательность, и так до тех пор, пока не переберет все возможные комбинации. Каждое возвращенное значение прогоняется через матрицу расстояний и рассчитывается общая дистанция. Такова идея

Не впихуйте невпихуемое. Я даже представить себе не могу, куда тут елд пристроить.

Ну а я могу. Вы лучше на вопрос ответьте

Если бы могли, то решили бы задачу. А не можете... Потому, что елд тут ни при чём.

Ц... Вам лишь бы языком почесать. Вопрос задан не про задачу, а про то как получить в итоге массив. А если не можете представить, при чем тут yield return, то перечитайте мой ответ.

У меня плюс-минус так и есть. Только в списке не чекпоинты, а расстояния. Плюс в том, что такая матрица просчитывается один раз и актуальна для любой комбинации в любом направлении. Ну и ещё - маршрут от точки А до ближайшей к ней - например, это будет Б - и от точки Б до ближайшей, не обязательно дает кратчайший путь из возможных. Не исключено, что кратчайший маршрут требует пойти не самым очевидным путём в каком-то месте, но это может дать преимущество на дальнейших шагах. Поэтому нужен полный перебор.

В курсе, из которого данное задание взято, предлагается реализовать оптимизацию в виде прекращения перебора, если промежуточный результат уже превышает найденный ранее (т.н. отсечение). Может это поможет)
За вариант решения спасибо, изучу.

Это хорошая идея, и её легко внедрить в моё решение.

Довёл решение до ума

Да нет, задача несложная. Я бы её сделал в первый день, но мне хотелось выполнить всё так, чтобы не менять логику методов, которые уже присутствовали в классе (задача предоставлялась с проектом, который нужно было доработать), а дополнить их, выполнив тем самым поставленную задачу. Если забить на это и просто делать так, как хочется, то задача на часок.

Сказки тут не нужно рассказывать про 1 час. Сначала нужно было просто решить задачу, а потом подстраивать решение под существующий проект.

Да какие сказки. Дан проект, в нем есть готовые методы для расчёта расстояния между парой точек и между всеми точками последовательности - их писать не нужно (в предыдущем проекте эти методы я писал сам). Переборные алгоритмы разбирались на лекциях, их нужно было только слегка видоизменить. Идея с матрицей расстояний - тоже (только в лекции была матрица цен). Ну и чего тут сложного? Если просто решать задачу "в лоб", то она решается легко. А вот сделать так, чтобы решение не требовало менять уже существующие методы проекта - это потребовало поломать голову.

"готовый метод для расчёта расстояния между ... всеми точками последовательности" никаким образом не применим для рекурсивного алгоритма. IEnumerable здесь тоже не подоходит, потому что алгоритм с отсечением сразу выдаёт наикратчайший маршрут либо ничего, если таковой не найден в текущей ветке.

И такие алгоритмы всегда реализуют на самом низком уровне, потому что любой IEnumerable здесь - это потеря производительности.

""готовый метод для расчёта расстояния..." никаким образом не применим для рекурсивного алгоритма". Интересно почему?)) Нет, мне-то без разницы, я лишь попытался вам объяснить что из себя представляет учебный проект. Мне этот метод тоже не нужен - у меня есть матрица расстояний.

Неприменим потому, что в рекурсивном алгоритме длина всего маршрута нигде одномоментно не вычисляется, а вычисляется по кусочкам (расстояниям между парами точек) и суммируется по мере углубления рекурсивного вызова.
